# error build: Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code (Xcode 14)

Tags: xcode, flutter

I updated Xcode to 14.0, and tried to run flutter app with flutter run.

After a bunch of warnings, flutter fails saying "Could not build the precompiled application for the device."
It's same when I build with Xcode.

```
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/tenna/Desktop/sflo/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/AppAuth/AppAuth-prefix.pch:2:
 ...

    note: Removed stale file
    '/Users/tenna/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fgophzrxcuuquoffvkeemrqvjrfz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/in_ap
    p_purchase_storekit/in_app_purchase_storekit.framework'

    note: Removed stale file
    '/Users/tenna/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fgophzrxcuuquoffvkeemrqvjrfz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/googl
    e_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.framework'

    note: Removed stale file
    '/Users/tenna/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fgophzrxcuuquoffvkeemrqvjrfz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Strip
    e/Stripe3DS2.bundle'

    note: Removed stale file
    '/Users/tenna/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fgophzrxcuuquoffvkeemrqvjrfz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/geoco
    ding/geocoding.framework'

    note: Removed stale file
    '/Users/tenna/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fgophzrxcuuquoffvkeemrqvjrfz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/gRPC-
    C++/gRPCCertificates-Cpp.bundle'

    note: Removed stale file
    '/Users/tenna/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fgophzrxcuuquoffvkeemrqvjrfz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/geolo
    cator_apple/geolocator_apple.framework'

    note: Removed stale file
    '/Users/tenna/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fgophzrxcuuquoffvkeemrqvjrfz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/flutt
    er_native_splash/flutter_native_splash.framework'

    note: Removed stale file
    '/Users/tenna/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fgophzrxcuuquoffvkeemrqvjrfz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/flutt
    er_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.framework'

    note: Removed stale file
    '/Users/tenna/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fgophzrxcuuquoffvkeemrqvjrfz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/flutt
    er_app_badger/flutter_app_badger.framework'

    note: Removed stale file
    '/Users/tenna/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fgophzrxcuuquoffvkeemrqvjrfz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/fireb
    ase_storage/firebase_storage.framework'

    note: Removed stale file
    '/Users/tenna/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fgophzrxcuuquoffvkeemrqvjrfz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/fireb
    ase_messaging/firebase_messaging.framework'

    note: Removed stale file
    '/Users/tenna/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fgophzrxcuuquoffvkeemrqvjrfz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/flutt
    er_image_compress/flutter_image_compress.framework'

    note: Removed stale file
    '/Users/tenna/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fgophzrxcuuquoffvkeemrqvjrfz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/fireb
    ase_crashlytics/firebase_crashlytics.framework'

    note: Removed stale file
    '/Users/tenna/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fgophzrxcuuquoffvkeemrqvjrfz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/fireb
    ase_core/firebase_core.framework'

    note: Removed stale file
    '/Users/tenna/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fgophzrxcuuquoffvkeemrqvjrfz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/fireb
    ase_dynamic_links/firebase_dynamic_links.framework'

    note: Removed stale file
    '/Users/tenna/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fgophzrxcuuquoffvkeemrqvjrfz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/fireb
    ase_auth/firebase_auth.framework'

    note: Removed stale file
    '/Users/tenna/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fgophzrxcuuquoffvkeemrqvjrfz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/cloud
    _functions/cloud_functions.framework'

    note: Removed stale file
    '/Users/tenna/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fgophzrxcuuquoffvkeemrqvjrfz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/fireb
    ase_analytics/firebase_analytics.framework'

    note: Removed stale file
    '/Users/tenna/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fgophzrxcuuquoffvkeemrqvjrfz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Strip
    eApplePay/StripeApplePay.framework'

    note: Removed stale file
    '/Users/tenna/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fgophzrxcuuquoffvkeemrqvjrfz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Strip
    e/Stripe.bundle'

    note: Removed stale file
    '/Users/tenna/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fgophzrxcuuquoffvkeemrqvjrfz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SFLO.
    app'

    note: Removed stale file
    '/Users/tenna/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fgophzrxcuuquoffvkeemrqvjrfz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SDWeb
    ImageWebPCoder/SDWebImageWebPCoder.framework'

    note: Removed stale file
    '/Users/tenna/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fgophzrxcuuquoffvkeemrqvjrfz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Strip
    eCore/StripeCore.framework'

    note: Removed stale file
    '/Users/tenna/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fgophzrxcuuquoffvkeemrqvjrfz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Strip
    eUICore/StripeUICore.framework'

    note: Removed stale file
    '/Users/tenna/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fgophzrxcuuquoffvkeemrqvjrfz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Strip
    eFinancialConnections/StripeFinancialConnections.framework'

    note: Removed stale file
    '/Users/tenna/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fgophzrxcuuquoffvkeemrqvjrfz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SDWeb
    Image/SDWebImage.framework'

    note: Removed stale file
    '/Users/tenna/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fgophzrxcuuquoffvkeemrqvjrfz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/absei
    l/absl.framework'

    note: Removed stale file
    '/Users/tenna/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fgophzrxcuuquoffvkeemrqvjrfz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Mantl
    e/Mantle.framework'

    note: Removed stale file
    '/Users/tenna/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fgophzrxcuuquoffvkeemrqvjrfz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Promi
    sesObjC/FBLPromises.framework'

    note: Removed stale file
    '/Users/tenna/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fgophzrxcuuquoffvkeemrqvjrfz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MTBBa
    rcodeScanner/MTBBarcodeScanner.framework'

    note: Removed stale file
    '/Users/tenna/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fgophzrxcuuquoffvkeemrqvjrfz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Strip
    e/Stripe.framework'

    note: Removed stale file
    '/Users/tenna/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fgophzrxcuuquoffvkeemrqvjrfz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Googl
    eUtilities/GoogleUtilities.framework'

    note: Removed stale file
    '/Users/tenna/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fgophzrxcuuquoffvkeemrqvjrfz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GTMAp
    pAuth/GTMAppAuth.framework'

    note: Removed stale file
    '/Users/tenna/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fgophzrxcuuquoffvkeemrqvjrfz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Googl
    eDataTransport/GoogleDataTransport.framework'

    note: Removed stale file
    '/Users/tenna/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fgophzrxcuuquoffvkeemrqvjrfz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Fireb
    aseMessaging/FirebaseMessaging.framework'

    note: Removed stale file
    '/Users/tenna/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fgophzrxcuuquoffvkeemrqvjrfz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GTMSe
    ssionFetcher/GTMSessionFetcher.framework'

    note: Removed stale file
    '/Users/tenna/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fgophzrxcuuquoffvkeemrqvjrfz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Fireb
    aseStorage/FirebaseStorage.framework'

    note: Removed stale file
    '/Users/tenna/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fgophzrxcuuquoffvkeemrqvjrfz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Fireb
    aseInstallations/FirebaseInstallations.framework'

    note: Removed stale file
    '/Users/tenna/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fgophzrxcuuquoffvkeemrqvjrfz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Fireb
    aseFunctions/FirebaseFunctions.framework'

    note: Removed stale file
    '/Users/tenna/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fgophzrxcuuquoffvkeemrqvjrfz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Fireb
    aseCoreDiagnostics/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics.framework'

    note: Removed stale file
    '/Users/tenna/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fgophzrxcuuquoffvkeemrqvjrfz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Fireb
    aseDynamicLinks/FirebaseDynamicLinks.framework'

    note: Removed stale file
    '/Users/tenna/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fgophzrxcuuquoffvkeemrqvjrfz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Fireb
    aseCrashlytics/FirebaseCrashlytics.framework'

    note: Removed stale file
    '/Users/tenna/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fgophzrxcuuquoffvkeemrqvjrfz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/gRPC-
    Core/grpc.framework'

    note: Removed stale file
    '/Users/tenna/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fgophzrxcuuquoffvkeemrqvjrfz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Fireb
    aseCore/FirebaseCore.framework'

    note: Removed stale file
    '/Users/tenna/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fgophzrxcuuquoffvkeemrqvjrfz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FMDB/
    FMDB.framework'

    note: Removed stale file
    '/Users/tenna/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fgophzrxcuuquoffvkeemrqvjrfz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Fireb
    aseFirestore/FirebaseFirestore.framework'

    note: Removed stale file
    '/Users/tenna/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fgophzrxcuuquoffvkeemrqvjrfz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Fireb
    aseAuth/FirebaseAuth.framework'

    note: Removed stale file
    '/Users/tenna/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fgophzrxcuuquoffvkeemrqvjrfz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/AppAu
    th/AppAuth.framework'

    note: Removed stale file
    '/Users/tenna/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fgophzrxcuuquoffvkeemrqvjrfz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/gRPC-
    C++/grpcpp.framework'

    note: Removed stale file
    '/Users/tenna/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fgophzrxcuuquoffvkeemrqvjrfz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Borin
    gSSL-GRPC/openssl_grpc.framework'

    warning: Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not
    specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run
    in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'BoringSSL-GRPC' from project
    'Pods')
    warning: Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not
    specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run
    in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'abseil' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not
    specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run
    in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'gRPC-Core' from project
    'Pods')
    warning: Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not
    specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run
    in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'gRPC-C++' from project
    'Pods')
    warning: Run script build phase 'Run Script' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To
    address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by
    unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'SFLO' from project 'Runner')
    warning: Run script build phase 'Thin Binary' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To
    address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by
    unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'SFLO' from project 'Runner')

    Result bundle written to path:
        /var/folders/cv/yb103sl92sn87wng_mvscb_80000gn/T/flutter_tools.MJYYvf/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirwtIiAC/temporary_xcresul
        t_bundle


Could not build the precompiled application for the device.

Error launching application on tenna (2).
```

I've tried excluding arm64, setting IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET to 15.0.
flutter clean, clean build cache etc.
But none of them works..

flutter doctor
.

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.2, on macOS 12.5 21G72 darwin-arm, locale ja-JP)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.0)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.71.0)
[✓] Connected device (5 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by removing VALID_ARCHS under Project -> Build settings -> User-Defined OR open project.pbxproj in Vscode, find VALID_ARCHS remove and save. Go back to Xcode, press Command + shift + k to clean build.

I got this from the link below:

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8035#issuecomment-764692977

Answer (score 0):

I face this issue several times in react native, and I am not sure my solutions will help or not.

Solution1*******

delete `Pods` and `Podfile.lock` then install again using `pod install` in ios folder

Solution2*******

this issue occur many times to me and What's wrong was there was some syntax issues (compile time issues) in my Components or js files.

Solution3******

I face this issue in my newly created project. I created the project in a new folder and folder name was of two words, then I just chnaged the folder name and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

Updated miscellaneous (flutter, pubspec, cocoapods).
Then it worked.

Comment: May I ask what exactly you updated? I'm having similar problems. After doing `flutter upgrade`, I restarted my IDE, did `flutter clean`, `flutter pub get`, `sudo gem install cocoapods`, `rm -rf Pods Podfile.lock` and `pod install`, but I'm still getting errors.

Comment: @Nathan did u find the solution?

Comment: @PRATHIV I think I ended up just undoing some changes with git until the problem disappeared... not sure what caused it in the first place